# Move DCIM .thumbnails to external SD

Tags: external-sd, thumbnails

My phone has 1.5 GB internal memory and it's always full with gallery thumbnails (500 MB) . Every time I delete it for more space after one day it's full again .

How can I move it to external micro SD memory ?

Answer (score 1):

Moving this folder to sd woun't help, cause android would recreate it. For me, this folder is shown as 6.5 GB (the real size was aprox 80 MB).

[WorldCAD Access](http://www.worldcadaccess.com/blog/2013/07/how-to-reclaim-1gb-from-your-androids-disk-space.html) posted an interesting solution, how to prevent Android for recreating at least the db files.

Another soultion, if you have root access would be to symlink this folder to sdcard. You can do this via command line or using tools like [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) or [FolderMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.fmount).

[here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66221/android-huge-thumbdata4-file-in-dcim-folder) you also can find some suggestions/solutions.

Answer (score -1):

500 megs seems awfully big for thumbnails. As for moving them to an external SD card, you can't move anything except music, videos, and pictures to an external card after the 4.1 or 4.2 version of the Android operating system. Since thumbnails are pictures of the pictures, they should move. Try doing it through a gallery program such as QuickPic. It's free. On the other hand, if the extension of the thumbnails is something else besides a standard image file extension (. Jpg,. Png, etc,)... Well, maybe you can't move them.